# Selecting record based on dates

Tags: postgresql, lag, distinct-values, lead

I have a sample source table [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4jyoMCicNSZpjMt4jFYoz5/1976) and currently, it is returning multiple records due to multiple tutors.

[image]

I want to select only the tutor_name if the exam_date is between the effective date and the next record's effective date.
Sample desired output:

[image]

Comment: `where exam_date between <earlier_date> and <later_date>`.

Comment: could you please elaborate?